# Не обновляется вывод переменной после ее изменения в другом методе flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Столкнулся с проблемой, что метод, который срабатывает при нажатии на кнопку меняет значения переменных, но в выводе они обновляются только после быстрой перезагрузки всего проекта.

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
 const Homepage({super.key});

 @override
 State<Homepage> createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {

 int newHeight = 0, newWight = 0, counter = 0;
 double x = 0, y = 0;

 void rand () {
   Random random = Random();
   newHeight = random.nextInt(384);
   newWight = random.nextInt(200);

   counter = counter + 1;
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     backgroundColor: Colors.black,
     appBar: AppBar(
       title: const Text('Custom Painter App'),
       backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
     ),
     body: SafeArea(
       child: Column(
         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
         children: [
           Center(
             child: Container(
               width: 384,
               height: 200,
               decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.indigo)),
                 child: SomeClass(
                   NewHeight: newHeight.toDouble(),
                   NewWight: newWight.toDouble(),
                   counter: counter,
                 ),
             ),
           ),
           Row(
             children: [
               Text("""
X: $newHeight
Y: $newWight
№: $counter""",
               style: const TextStyle(
               fontSize: 22,
               fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
               color: Colors.yellow),
               ),
             ],
           ),
           ElevatedButton(style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,), onPressed: (rand), child: const Text('Новая точка')),
           ],
       ),
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

В другом проекте писал точно так же и все работало(при нажатии на кнопку добавлялся символ к строке и в выводе она обновлялась автоматически после каждого нажатия). Кто знает в чем может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Для реактивных переменных во флаттер необходимо использовать setState. Используй это в функции rand()

```
setState() { counter = counter +1 }
```